# How can I create a menu item corresponding to a link to another (external) site?

Tags: routes, navigation

In my menu I can create an **internal** link corresponding to a path like → '/path/to/node'.

But when trying to create a link to an external website (like `→ http://www.external.com`), the link actually becomes `→ https://www.mywebsite.com/http://www.external.com`

So basically, external links are not recognized as external. But instead they get added to the base URL.

How can I make this to work?

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to add external link to menu items as this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7424500/drupal-adding-external-links-to-custom-menus) confirms it too.